# Shared instance of CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, location, singleton

I was trying to create simple shared instance of CLLocationManager for my app.

There was no problem creating shared instance:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationHandlerDelegate: class {
    func locationHandlerDidUpdateLocation(location: CLLocation?)
    func locationHandlerDidFailWithError(error: NSError)
}

class LocationHandler: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var location: CLLocation?
    weak var delegate: LocationHandlerDelegate?

    static let sharedInstance = LocationHandler()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    // MARK: -
    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate functions
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        delegate?.locationHandlerDidUpdateLocation(locations.last)
        self.location = locations.last

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        delegate?.locationHandlerDidFailWithError(error)

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I call my shared instance from another class:

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, LocationHandlerDelegate {
        super.viewDidLoad() {

        LocationHandler.sharedInstance.delegate = self        

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            LocationHandler.sharedInstance.locationManager.requestLocation()
        } else {
            LocationHandler.sharedInstance.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
}
...
    // MARK: - LocationHandlerDelegate function
    func locationHandlerDidUpdateLocation(location: CLLocation?) {
        if let location = location {
            print("Current lcoation: \(location)")
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    }

    func locationHandlerDidFailWithError(error: NSError) {
        print("Error finding lcoation: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

None of CLLocationManagerDelegate functions in my LocationHandler are called. 
But if in TodayViewController I write

```
LocationHandler.sharedInstance.locationManager.delegate = self
```

instead of

```
LocationHandler.sharedInstance.delegate = self
```

and I implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` functions in my `TodayViewController` instead of `LocationHandler` then those delegate functions are called. So I guess there may be some problem with instancing? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: sharedInstance is an instance of LocationHandler, not CLLocationManager so the delegate properties are different. The delegation pattern doesn't really work with a singleton anyway as you can only have a single delegate. You should probably use something lie NSNotificationCenter

Comment: But shouldn't it also be instance of locationManager since CLLocationManager property is implemented in LocationHandler?

Comment: No. Your location manager doesn't subclass CLLocationManager so it doesn't inherit any of that classes properties

Comment: And could you please recommend me some way for good location handling in several view controllers?

Comment: Your approach is probably OK, but you will probably need to post NSNotifications from your delegate methods with each interested class subscribing to those